# Twitter Bootstrap Themeroller

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, themeroller

Is there any themeroller application like [jQuery UI Themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) for [Twitter Bootrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). It would be fun and easy to design and generate custom theme for [Twitter Bootrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/).

Comment: http://stylebootstrap.info/ for Bootstrap v2

Comment: check out http://www.bootstrapthemeroller.com/

Comment: @hellojava thank you, I was looking for something like that

Comment: I created a [Bootstrap ThemeRoller](https://www.bootpress.org/themeroller/) for v3 that you can copy and paste .less files to edit, or just start from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no themeroller-like sites for the bootstrap, but you can find certain premade themes on the internet such as the ones available in this site: http://bootswatch.com/. Of course, you can always make your own by using such tools as the [Colorzilla Gradient](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) editor and [Colour Lovers](http://www.colourlovers.com/) to find matching colors that you might like.

Comment: actually there are  bootstrapthemeroller.com

Comment: @hellojava aww neet, at the time of writing i couldn't find any.

Comment: @AndresIlich the domain was registered after your answer (`2012-06-23`). :-)

Comment: @Alastair I knew I wasn't crazy :P

Comment: bootstrapthemeroller.com only contains advertisement today.